# R future multisession Error: values() is defunct in future (>= 1.20.0). Use value() instead

Tags: r, r-future

I had a function successfully using `future` `multisession`, but with an update of `future` received the below error, which I have not figured out how to solve:

Error: values() is defunct in future (>= 1.20.0). Use value() instead.

Please see below example (where I am not using values(), but still get the error):

```
future::plan(future::multisession)

test_function <- function(x){
  x <- x+5
  return(x)
}

test_data <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))

tuning_results <- furrr::future_map(
  .x = test_data,
  .f = test_function)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by updating the `furrr` package.